# Type error while scraping location of circle K location across Canada

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, typeerror

I'm currently trying to scrape circle K locations across Canada. I found that if I just do pages I get close to what I think are all locations across the world.The end goal is to parse the individual location data into excel.

My problem is I get a error:

```
Match_address = store["address"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am wondering why I am getting this and if anyone can point it out that would be great! I'm a geographer not really a coder, so I might just be missing some obvious stuff.I included my original code and the raw output that I am trying to parse out.If more clarification is needed I can update the details.

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import csv 

x = range(0,955)

for pages in x:
  url = f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat=49.2609&lng=-123.1139&services=&region=global&page={pages}"
  payload={}
  headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?address=Toronto,Ontario,Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

stores = json.loads(response.text)
 
with open('circleK12.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow([
        "address",
        "city",
        ])

    for store in stores['stores'].values():
        row = []
        Match_address = store["address"]
        Match_city = store["city"]


        row.append(Match_address)
        row.append(Match_city)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

```
{'count': 10, 'page': 904, 'division': 'europe', 'stores': {'10779': {'cost_center': '10779', 'ccs': '2', 'address': 'Usserød Kongevej 23', 'city': 'Hørsholm', 'latitude': '55.883258902243', 'longitude': '12.497684383153', 'franchise': '0', 'franchise_brand': None, 'store_brand': 'CIRCLEK', 'display_brand': 'CIRCLEK', 'op_status': 'Open', 'division_name': 'europe', 'tactic_division_name': 'europe', 'distance': '5276.31913275613', 'country': 'DK', 'url': '/store-locator/DK/hoersholm/usseroed-kongevej-23/10779', 'services': [{'name': 'EU_ROUTEX_ATLAS', 'display_name': 'Routex Atlas', 'icon': 'FeatureRoutexAtlas'}, {'name': 'EU_SIMPLY_GREAT_COFFEE', 'display_name': 'Simply Great Coffee', 'icon': 'FeatureCoffee'}, {'name': 'EU_CARWASH', 'display_name': 'Car wash', 'icon': 'FeatureCarWash'}, {'name': 'EU_TRAILER_RENTAL', 'display_name': 'Trailer rental', 'icon': 'FeatureTrailerRental'}, {'name': 'EU_HIGH_SPEED_PUMP', 'display_name': 'High Speed Pump', 'icon': 'FeatureHighSpeedPump'}, {'name': 'EU_MOBILE_PAYMENTS_CARWASH', 'display_name': 'Mobile Payments Carwash', 'icon': 'FeatureMobilePaymentsCarwash'}, {'name': 'EU_MOBILE_PAYMENTS_FUEL', 'display_name': 'Mobile Payments Fuel', 'icon': 'FeatureMobilePaymentsFuel'}, {'name': 'EU_SMOOTHIE_JUICE', 'display_name': 'Smoothie/Juice', 'icon': 'FeatureSmoothieJuice'}]}, '10296': {'cost_center': '10296', 'ccs': '2', 'address': 'Rådalsvej 81', 'city': 'Jyllinge', 'latitude': '55.760259617670', 'longitude': '12.111481669840', 'franchise': '0', 'franchise_brand': None, 'store_brand': 'CIRCLEK', 'display_brand': 'CIRCLEK', 'op_status': 'Open', 'division_name': 'europe', 'tactic_division_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check your data `stores['stores']` you could see that it has keys as number and under those numbers there are `address`.

So, you'll eventually need to go through one more for loop

```
store['stores'].keys()
```

```
dict_keys(['11201', '11170', '11020', '11094', '11096', '11159', '11156', '11207', '11168', '11187'])
```

Under those number (ex. '11201', '11170'...) there are keys that you are looking for such as 'address', or 'city'.

you could try

```
for key_num in stores['stores']:
    store = stores['stores'][key_num]:  # one more step added
    row = []
    Match_address = store["address"]
    Match_city = store["city"]
...
```

Or to be simple you could just do the code below instead of adding another line.

```
for store in stores['stores'].values():
    row = []
    Match_address = store["address"]
    Match_city = store["city"]
...
```

New attempt -

```
row = []
for pages in x:
    url = f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat=49.2609&lng=-123.1139&services=&region=global&page={pages}"
    payload={}
    headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?address=Toronto,Ontario,Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    stores = json.loads(response.text)

    tmp_row = []
    for store in stores['stores'].values():
        Match_address = store["address"]
        Match_city = store["city"]

        tmp_row.append([Match_address, Match_city])
    row.extend(tmp_row) 
    
with open('circleK12.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([
        "address",
        "city",
        ])
    writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I am not getting back anything. Did I input ur suggestion wrong?

Comment: Can you show me how it's not working? what was the error? plus I tried it on the same website and it worked for me

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\00joh\Desktop\Code run demo\john .py", line 46, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\00joh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 20: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I edited the code I posted, is it different than what you got? Cause I feel I just copied and pasted the suggestion u gave wrong into my code

Comment: The code you edited above works fine with me and I'm able to get the `circleK12.csv` file just fine. Can you show which line occurs the error? It seems like an encoding error. Try doing `with open('circleK12.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as CSVFile`

Comment: I re edited the code one more time, You can see the changes. The circleK12.csv i still blanks for me. btw thanks for the help, I need this for my internship lol

Comment: Also, I get no error just get back nothing

Comment: Do you mean you get a blank file? what is your result for `print(row)`? Also, I added a code that you might try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234354/discussion-between-john-muir-and-sammy).